# In what situation would we combine tensors from different points in a tensor field?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

In my lecture notes it emphasises that a tensor $C^{abc}_{def} = A^{abc}_{def} + B^{abc}_{def}$ is only also a tensor itself if $A^{abc}_{def}$ and $B^{abc}_{def}$ are evaluated *at the same point in a tensor field*. This makes sense to me since for non-linear co-ordinate transformations, the transformation matrices would be dependent on position within the tensor field and thus would transform $A^{abc}_{def}$ and $B^{abc}_{def}$ differently in such a way that you could not have transformation matrices for $C^{abc}_{def}$.

My only real question is, in what situation would we even want to try to sum tensors from different points in a tensor field, so why do my lecture notes bother to mention it? (This confusion could be stemming from the fact that tensors always seem to be used in the context of tensor fields in all the situations in physics I've seen so far). Especially since, if we did this, how would we assign a point in space for $C^{abc}_{def}$ if it is composed of tensors acting at different points?

Also, to check, there is nothing special about addition here right? If we instead had $C^{ab} = A^{a}B^{b}$, but evaluated $A^{a}$ and $B^{b}$ at different points in the tensor field, that also would mean that $C^{ab}$ isn't a tensor right?

Comment: One reason one might _try_ to do such a thing might be to define a derivative $dT^a = T^a(x)-T^a(x+dx)$.

Comment: @jacob1729 so is the point of the statement so that it should be clear that if one did define a deriative of a tensor field like that, one shouldn't expect it to be a tensor too. Is that it? Thanks

Comment: @jacob1729 and am I correct that this is not just an issue for addition/subtraction, but any combining of tensors at different points in a tensor field?